# Do "surjective" degree zero maps exist?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Is there a map $f\colon X \to Y$ of closed, connected, smooth and orientable $n$-dimensional manifolds such that the degree of $f$ is 0 but $f$ is not **homotopic** to a non-surjective map?

**Added**: The motivation is: There is a "mild version" of the Nearby Langrangian conjecture stating: any exact Lagrangian manifold $X \to T^*Y$ has non-zero degree when composed with the projection $T^*Y \to Y$. It is known that the map is always surjective. I am looking at a **possible** inbetween stating that the map cannot be homotoped to a non-surjective map.

Comment: I seems like it will be very very hard to prove that a given map is *not homotopic* to a non-surjective map. 

Comment: I added the condition closed - which I initially just forgot.

Comment: Partial answer: If $Y=S^n$, it follows by the Theorem of Hopf that the degree determines the homotopy class. It's on the last page before the exercises in Milnor's Topology from a Differentiable Viewpoint. This gives a negative answer for spheres, but I don't know about the general case.  Also, by closed, do you mean closed as a submanifold of euclidean space?

Comment: "Closed" is standard terminology for a compact manifold without boundary.

Comment: Ah, I've never heard of that before.

Comment: If you're getting into this "nearby Lagrangian" stuff, make sure you're up to date! You need to know the theorem of Fukaya-Seidel-Smith/Nadler about Maslov-zero exact Lagrangians in simply connected cotangent bundles, and the recent work of Abouzaid about cotangent fibres, relevant to relaxing the simple connectedness assumption.

Comment: Yes I known about all this. I am thinking in the totally general setting. No vanishing Maslov class.

Comment: @ThomasKragh If you remove the smoothness, there actually are continous maps $S^n \to S^n$ of degree 0 that are surjective!

Comment: @Bogdan: You don't need to remove smoothness for that, and that is not the question. You may have missed the part "homotopic to".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is a theorem of H. Hopf that a map between connected, closed, orientable n-manifolds of degree 0 is homotopic to a map that misses a point, when n > 2. See D. B. A. Epstein, The degree of a map. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 16 1966 369--383, for a "modern" discussion including the analogous situation in the non-orientable case. The same result holds for n = 2, but is more difficult and is due to Kneser. See Richard Skora, The degree of a map between surfaces. 
Math. Ann. 276 (1987), no. 3, 415--423, for a thorough discussion of the non-orientable case in dimension 2.

Comment: Great - Thanks! I am assuming that you forgot the connected assumption. 

Comment: Right. "All manifolds are connected unless otherwise stated." I'll fix it for the record.